# Is there a way to take certain parts of text from a word file to store in a variable

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

Im trying to to implement a system that can take certain data from a contract that is a word  file , taking only certain parts of the text in the word file like the Contractor's name , the billing , etc.
Only thing that made sense was using a special character and using java tokenizer but including special characters in a contract that will be presented to the client doesn't seem right , so is there a certain library or tool that can do this? up till now I used Apache Poi , Jsoup and DOCX4J.

Comment: Is the contract in a well known, stable, fixed format? Or can the layout vary from document to document?

Comment: @Gagravarr Each contract is different in terms of categories and so on so it needs a dynamic approach.

Comment: You probably want to look at things from NLP then, eg NER = Named Entity Recognition